# Unicode characters in emacs term-mode

Tags: unicode, emacs, elisp

I use ansi-term for my normal terminal sessions.  I tend to use unicode characters in my prompt to do things like set the trailing character based on the type of source control I'm using.

I use the character "±" as my prompt for git repositories.

In Emacs' ansi-term, my prompt isn't rendered as unicode, and shows as "\302\261". Displaying the current coding system shows that it defaults to utf-8-unix for input to the process, but I get raw binary as the decoding output. I can hit C-c RET p to change the encoding and decoding coding systems.  I'm drawing a blank as to how to set this automatically when I start a terminal?  I've tried adding to term-mode-hook to set the buffer's coding system to no avail.  I think I've found what I'm looking for in term.el, but I don't care to tweak the distribution elisp, and it appears the raw binary was added to fix a bug somewhere else.

**EDIT:** This was unclear originally.  I'm having issues setting the default process coding system for ansi-term running under Cocoa-ized Emacs 23.3 on MacOS.  Emacs itself isn't running in a terminal, my terminal is running in Emacs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After getting a better understanding of `term.el`, the following works:

```
(defadvice ansi-term (after advise-ansi-term-coding-system)
    (set-buffer-process-coding-system 'utf-8-unix 'utf-8-unix))
(ad-activate 'ansi-term)
```

Trying this with `term-mode-hook` is broken because in term.el, `term-mode-hook` is called before switching to the terminal buffer, so `set-buffer-process-coding-system` breaks due to the lack of a process associated with the buffer.

Comment: Am I right in thinking term mode executing the hook before switching is unusual? Maybe it should be fixed.

Comment: Hmm: `"‘set-buffer-process-coding-system’ is for interactive use only; use ‘set-process-coding-system’ instead." :warning "*Compile-Log*"`

Comment: The term buffer is always current when `term-mode-hook` runs. The actual reason for the "lack of process" issue is that `make-term` and `term-ansi-make-term` call `term-mode` *before the process is created*. (`term` and `ansi-term` subsequently call `term-mode` again, so the problem isn't as obvious as it might be when you look at the code.)  As David Goodlad's answer shows, the best solution is to use `term-exec-hook` instead, which runs after creating the process.

Answer (score 17):

The following worked for me:

```
(add-hook 'term-exec-hook
          (function
           (lambda ()
             (set-buffer-process-coding-system 'utf-8-unix 'utf-8-unix))))
```

`ansi-term` seems to ignore the `default-process-coding-system` variable, so I had to set it buffer-locally after it executes my shell.

Comment: That does not work; the hook runs before the buffer is switched to via ansi-term.  I've figured it via defadvise however.

Comment: Something between this and @MattErickson's tip fixed my wagon. I can use `zsh`, `rinari`, and `rails c` in Emacs now!

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
(set-terminal-coding-system 'utf-8-unix)
```

That's `C-x RET t` not `C-x RET p`.

---

So `C-x RET p` helps?
Unless `C-h v default-process-coding-system` is `(utf-8-unix . utf-8-unix)` try

```
(setq default-process-coding-system '(utf-8-unix . utf-8-unix))
```

Comment: I think you meant "C-x RET t"

Comment: As I understand it, that sets the coding system Emacs is using to interpret the terminal that it's running inside of.

Comment: On Emacs 23.3 on MacOS 10.7, setting the terminal coding system doesn't do anything, setting the process coding system makes it work.  I'm running Emacs through Cocoa and not as a command-line app- upon looking at my original question, that was unclear.

Comment: I adjusted my answer, see if that helps.

Comment: I already have that variable set in my .emacs to that.  The source for term.el seems to be forcing it to raw encoding, citing some bug from somewhere.  I've tried also adding a term-mode-hook, but that seems to just hang the terminal.

Comment: ```(set-terminal-coding-system 'utf-8-unix)``` worked like charm. emacs 24.5