# Chinese characters in emacs --no-window-system on windows

Tags: emacs

I recently started using emacs on Android in Termux. My projects feature some chinese characters, which are displayed there just fine.

[image: Emacs in Termux]

When later opening the same file in Emacs on Windows, I was disappointed to see them displayed as `\xxxx`

[image: Emacs on Windows]

I am not sure how to search for a solution, because I do not what the problem is.

The only thing I found related to my problem is this:

[Unicode characters in emacs term-mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6820051/unicode-characters-in-emacs-term-mode)

but it did no help me solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell what's going on by looking at the first few characters in the mode line.  In Termux, it says `UUU`, but in Windows it says `DDU`.  These three characters stand for:

1. the coding system for keyboard input
2. the coding system for terminal output
3. the coding system of the file in the buffer

`U` stands for UTF-8, while `D` stands for various DOS code pages.  (You can find this using `M-x list-coding-systems`.  This is all described in [the Mode Line section of the Emacs manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Mode-Line.html).)

So this means that Emacs is reading the file correctly, but it thinks that the terminal is unable to display the Chinese characters, so it uses the `\uxxxx` notation as a fallback.  I'm not sure how to get this to work properly in a Windows terminal, but try `M-x set-terminal-coding-system` with `utf-8` - it might just work.

---

As an aside, if you run Emacs as a "normal" Windows application instead of in a terminal, the characters should display correctly automatically, so if there is a particular problem preventing you from doing so, it might be worth trying to fix that instead.

Comment: one step closer to solving it :) the reason I use --no-window-system is because cmd.exe provides a white-on-black colorscheme while graphics is black-on-white

Comment: Try `M-x customize-themes`. One of those colour themes should suit your taste, or you could create your own.

Comment: wombat is nice. thx :) I leave the question open though. maybe somebody needs to really fix this issue one day

Comment: If the answer answers your question, please accept it. Closed questions are still searchable.